# How to implement dynamic page building in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-pageview

I am trying to know to build a page in flutter. I am using firestore database

I know how to build a list using Stream or ListView.Builder. and automatically list items are are created as per the number of documents.

I want to build pages similar to the above said list items according to the number of documents which may include nested lists or arrays of items.

How may I achieve it?

Comment: You can use PageView.builder just like ListView.builder

Comment: thanks for the advice I will work on this and learn it @JagrajSingh